# The phrase "À croire que"

Tags: sens, expressions, usage, locutions

> Je n'aurais pas cru vous revoir ici. À croire qu'ils n'ont trouvé personne de compétent pour vous remplacer.

What exactly does this phrase mean in this sentence?

And how would you use the "À croire que" in some other examples?

**UPDATE**

So does my example sentence mean that:

"I wouldn't have thought to see you again here. (But you have come back here!)

So **you/one would (reasonably) think that** they couldn't find anyone competent enough to replace you. (although in fact they did find one.)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"à croire que XXX" means that the guy talking is so suprised that he could have come to believe that XXX.

XXX is something that would explain the situation, but which is not likely at all. It is a not serious hypothesis, often a hyperbole or a joke.

Here an example:

> Tu es déjà au bureau alors qu'il n'est même pas 7h, à croire que tu es resté ici toute la nuit !
>
> Il m'a regardé bizarrement, à croire qu'il avait vu la Vierge.
>
> Il ne s'arrêtait pas de parler, à croire qu'on lui avait lancé un sort.

Comment: So does my example sentence mean that: "I wouldn't have thought to see you again here. (But you have come back here!) So **you/one would (reasonably) think that** they couldn't find anyone competent enough to replace you. (although in fact they did find one.)"

Answer (score 3):

Selon [http://www.wordreference.com/fren/à%20croire%20que](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/%C3%A0%20croire%20que), ça me paraît signifier:

> You would think...
>
> It's hard to believe...

Étant donnés les faits, c'est possible que l'expression démontre l'incrédulité qui s'oppose à la croyance populaire, ou d'une croyance étonnante.

Voici des examples:

> À croire qu'il ne tromperait jamais sa femme, malgré sa grossesse. Ça m'étonne bien.
>
> C'est à croire que les enfants boufferaient des légumes pour maintenir leur corps.

Comment: Une grammaire indique que _à croire que_  en tête de phrase, après un point, s'analyse comme si c'était une réduction de _c'est à croire que_ et donc ces exemples sont aussi bien intéressants !

Answer (score 0):

CROIRE QUE : Considérer comme vraisemblable, probable<sup>*1*</sup>.

*À croire que* peut être remplacé ici par *il est vraisemblable que*, ou  *il probable que*.

---

***Complément***

Dans un autre contexte, on pourrait positiver la 'vraisemblable probabilité'... ou la nier,

« J'aime à croire que » => *espérer, souhaiter<sup>1</sup>*,

> Tout porte *à croire que* c'est vrai (... que c'est faux)<sup>*1*</sup>.

... mais remplacer *À croire qu'ils*... par *Espérons qu'ils...* ou *Souhaitons qu'ils...* n'est pas adéquat dans ce contexte, puisque la personne ne devrait pas être là aux yeux du locuteur, elle semble retenue contre son gré.

Parmi les synonymes de  CROIRE QUE :
*estimer, se figurer, imaginer, juger, penser, présumer, supposer<sup>1</sup>* ;
... ils évoquent chacun une nuance dépendant du contexte, et pour la phrase de la question, on pourrait en choisir un et le mettre à la première personne du singulier pour donner le point de vue du locuteur.

---

***P.S.*** suite au commentaire de [Stéphane](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/79/st%C3%A9phane-gimenez) :

> [L'utilisation de croire] dans la locution conjonctive *à croire que* n'est absolument pas anodine. La signification dans ce contexte est grosso modo *À voir cela, on **pourrait** croire*. Et cela peut s'employer lorsque la supposition est peu probable ou, encore mieux, lorsqu'elle est clairement impossible. Tout le contraire de croire…

Parmi les synonymes *on présumerait, on supposerait* me semble les plus proches de *on pourrait*, dans le sens où l'on évoque une possibilité incertaine, non définitive.

Bien que le Robert, quand il traite  *croire **que***, n'inclue pas le verbe *pouvoir* dans la liste des synonymes, il n'est pas absurde de l'y admettre, sur le modèle de l'exemple cité dans le complément :

> On *pourrait croire que* c'est impossible.

Les synonymes du verbe *croire* (de *confier*, fig. *avoir confiance*) :  *accepter, admettre<sup>1</sup>* et donc leur antonymes *refuser, nier<sup>2</sup>* appellent une opinion tranchée, qui n'inclue pas les nuances de ceux de *croire que*.

---

<sup>1 - *extraits du Robert.*</sup>
<sup>2 - *pas de références trouvées pour l'antonyme de* croire.</sup>

Comment: L'expression suggère exactement le contraire…

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez ... Bigre !! C'est un match Stéphane contre Robert (le nouveau petit, édité en 1999) : §4 CROIRE QUE : Considérer comme vraisemblable, probable... Origine de ma réponse -- J'ai ajouté un exemple demandé dans la question, c'est une nuance 'positive' mais non contraire. Les synonymes ne rentrent pas en contradiction avec la première réponse.

Comment: Tu donnes l'une des définitions de croire. On dirait que tu ne remarques même pas que son utilisation dans la locution conjonctive *à croire que* n'est absolument pas anodine. La signification dans ce contexte est grosso modo *À voir cela, on **pourrait** croire*. Et cela peut s'employer lorsque la supposition est peu probable ou, encore mieux, lorqu'elle est clairement impossible. Tout le contraire de croire…

Comment: I wonder if this expression is an equivalent of "**To think that ... !**" in English, which means that the speaker finds something surprising. "**To think that** they haven't found anyone competent enough to replace you (**is surprising**)!"

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez -- Ayant cité ton commentaire, droit de réponse et/ou de modification totalement ouvert dans le P.S. et dans la gestion des commentaires y afférent.

Answer (score -1):

C'est une expression mettant en doute la crédibilité de l'assertion venant ensuite.

La phrase :

> A croire qu'il devient sourd...

Pourrait être reformulée ainsi :

> Je doute qu'il devient sourd...

Answer (score -5):

**à croire que ... = il faut croire que ...**

= on peut croire que ... / On peut penser que ...

= Il est probable que ...

Comment: Cette réponse n'explique rien. L'égalité n'a aucun sens.