# Nous sommes nombreux à croire que …

Tags: syntaxe

Je suis tombé sur [cette publicité](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYahQ.jpg) à la page 195/197 dans [*le Guide touristique officiel 2019-2020 des Îles de la Madeleine*](http://m3.ithq.qc.ca/collection/IlesdelaMadeleineFR.pdf).

> [Entreprise] fier partenaire du développement de son milieu
>
> Nous sommes nombreux à croire qu’appuyer les événements touristiques et les organismes locaux permet d’assurer la vitalité de notre région.
>
> Pour [entreprise], c'est une façon de contribuer au mieux-être de notre communauté et d'assurer sa prospérité.

D'après [ce site Web](https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/quelle-est-la-difference-de-sens-entre-a-croire-que-cest-comme-si-et-on-dirait-que) et [The phrase "À croire que"](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/19068/1995), « À croire que » ≈ « C’est comme si » ≈ « On dirait que ».

1. La conjugaison singulière de 'permet'
   entraîne que le sujet doit être singulier. Le sujet est 'appuyer les évènements touristiques
   et les organismes locaux', oui ?
2. Si je substitue « c'est comme si/on dirait que  » à  « à croire que », la 1e phrase devient :

> 3. Nous sommes nombreux **c'est comme si/on dirait que** qu’appuyer les événements [...] permet d’assurer la vitalité [...].

4. Mais cette phrase est une parataxe, car 'Nous sommes nombreux' et **c'est comme si/on dirait que qu'appuyer [...]** sont des propositions indépendantes.
5. De plus, que signifie 'Nous sommes nombreux' ici ? Nombreux pour qui et pour faire quoi ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ Oui

2/ Non, ne pas confondre « à croire que » [employé seul](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/19068/17649) ou avec « c'est » (C'est à croire) et « à croire que  » employé comme complément d'un adjectif ou d'un verbe ; ici c'est du complément qu'il s'agit, complément de « nombreux ».

3/ Non

4/ Non

5/ « Nous sommes nombreux à croire » signifie « le nombre des personnes qui croient (qqc) est grand ».

Cette tournure permet de faire deux assertions avec un seul verbe conjugué : « Nous sommes nombreux à faire (qqc). » et « Ce (qqc) est de croire à (qqc). »

Des paraphrases  de cette phrase

- Nous, les gens qui croyons qu'appuyer les événements touristiques et les organismes locaux permet d’assurer la vitalité de notre région, sommes nombreux. (*insistance sur le nombre*)
- Nous  croyons en grand nombre, qu'appuyer les événements touristiques et les organismes locaux permet d’assurer la vitalité de notre région. (*assez fidèle à l'original, qui insiste sur l'opinion plutôt que sur le nombre*)

Answer (score 5):

Tu fais une erreur dans l'analyse de la phrase.  Nous n'avons pas affaire à l'expression *à croire que* mais à *croire que* dans son sens habituel.  On pourrait le remplacer par *penser* :

- Nous sommes nombreux à penser qu’appuyer les événements touristiques et les organismes locaux permet d’assurer la vitalité de notre région.

Quant à *nous sommes nombreux à*, on pourrait le paraphraser et dire *beaucoup d'entre nous* :

- Beaucoup d'entre nous croyons qu’appuyer les événements touristiques et les organismes locaux permet d’assurer la vitalité de notre région.

Si on traduisait en anglais, on pourrait dire :

- Many of us believe that…

Pour pouvoir analyser la phrase en construction parataxique, les deux phrases juxtaposées devraient être séparées par une virgule :

- Nous sommes nombreux,  à croire qu’appuyer les événements touristiques et les organismes locaux permet d’assurer la vitalité de notre région.

C'est théoriquement possible, mais cette phrase aurait un sens tout à fait différent.

Answer (score 4):

La construction n'est pas l'expression verbale *à croire que*, main un **infinitif complément de l'adjectif** (Grevisse, *Bon Usage, 14e éd.*, §915). Essentiellement la forme généralisée de la même construction qu'on retrouve dans des expressions comme *apte à*, *enclin à* ou *prompt à*.

La construction avec *nombreux* n'est pas très figée, et on peut très bien dire *nous sommes nombreux qui croyons [...]*. Ainsi, le quatrième de couverture (ou du moins le résumé officiel) de *Nous avons fait l'amour, ils ont fait la guerre* par Jean Botherel [dit](https://www.archambault.ca/livres/nous-avons-fait-l%27amour-ils-ont-fait-la-guerre/bothorel-jean/9782226324993/?id=2137996&cat=1884314) "Nous sommes nombreux qui avons agi, qui avons vieilli", mais formuler *[...] nombreux à voir agi, à avoir vieilli*, serait tout à fait légitime.